# How to use Stetho with okhttp3 for network inspection?

Tags: java, android, okhttp, stetho

I launched the app the Android emulator (Genymotion). Problem is I cannot inspect anything in Chrome Dev Tools (see screenshot below). Any tips ?

[Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)

Google Chrome Dev Tools in (address bar)

This is what I see after entering this URL in Chrome
chrome://inspect/

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

TrainerWorkoutApplication.java

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho;

public class TrainerWorkoutApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Stetho.initialize(Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
        .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this))
        .build());
    } // onCreate()

} // TrainerWorkoutApplication
```

LogInActivity.java

```
package com.trainerworkout.trainerworkout.activity;

//...

/** As a personal trainer I need to log in so that I can have access to the app. */
public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static OkHttpClient client;
    private OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        builder.addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(context));
        builder.addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(context));

        builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());

        client = builder.build();
    } // onCreate()

    //...

} // LogInActivity
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //...
} // android

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'
} // dependencies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I think the Application class should be in the application package and not in the java package. Also, make sure the application class is declared in the

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.trainerworkout.trainerworkout"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <application
        ...
        android:name=".TrainerWorkout">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image]

For more info on how to use Stetho I recommend this tutorial.

[Debugging Android Apps with Facebook's Stetho](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/debugging-android-apps-with-facebooks-stetho--cms-24205)